# Syntax error in UPDATE statement - MS. Access

Tags: sql, vb.net

I tried to update my database, But the syntax error is keep coming. I tried to find the syntax error but i cant find it. this database is password protected one.

```
sql12 = "SELECT * FROM x Where id='rd1996'"  
da12 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql12, con)    
da12.Fill(ds12, "tbl12")

Dim cd As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da12)

ds12.Tables("tbl12").Rows(0).Item(1) = txtNNM.Text
ds12.Tables("tbl12").Rows(0).Item(2) = txtNPS.Text
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds12.Tables("tbl12")

da12.Update(ds12, "tbl12")
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The most common reason for this is that one of your column names is either a reserved word or contains spaces or other special characters.  When you use a wildcard in your query, the command builder doesn't escape the column names in the action commands and a syntax error results.  You have three options:

1. Change your column name(s) to something that doesn't need escaping. 
   You should do this even if you use one of the other options.
2. Don't use a wildcard in your query and instead specify each column,
   in which case you will have to quote at least the offending
   column(s) and the command builder will follow your lead.
3. Set the `QuotePrefix` and `QuoteSuffix` properties of your command
   builder so it will wrap all your column names in those values.  For
   Access, you would use "[" and "]" respectively.